# Spring Roo: dropdown by ajax or jquery

Tags: json, spring, jquery, dojo, spring-roo

In a page there are  35  texts fields .I want to  manage if  Product Not Procured   then only 9 fields shown on a page ,after filling the page

When we change the status to Product Procured Not Shipped then it shows another 6 field show,after filling the page

When we changed the status Order Shipped then it shows 9 field ,
then after filling the page

When we changed the status Order Delivered then it shows 3 field ,
then after filling the page ..........
Please help me

Comment: `public enum OrderStatus {
 
   
 Product_Not_Procured,
 Product_Procured_Not_Shipped,
 Order_Shipped, 
 Order_Delivered,
 Order_Returned,
 Order_Cancelled;}`

Comment: I have this status..How i managed ..when i choose one status..it automatically changes the below field

Comment: How I compare Enums Constant in Jsp..pls help

Answer (score 1):

To hide an element use

```
    dojo.style(elementId, "visibility", "hidden");
```

To check the value of Enum

```
    var orderStatus = document.getElementById('_elementName_id').value;
    if(orderStatus != "Product_Not_Procured")
```